# Script for multiple .cpp files in VsCode (tasks.json) using g++ compiler

Tags: json, shell, g++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm making a script so I can build C++ projects in Visual Studio Code in tasks.json using g++ compiler commands (I use Linux).
Currently, my script only builds the .cpp file that I'm currently seeing and I want it to build and compile all of the .cpp files in a specific folder.

This is my command script fragment:

```
"command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I/${workspaceFolder}/include"
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ]
```

I don't know if I need to change the `-g ${file}` or only the `${file}`.

Comment: The command-line arguments are listed one by one. You can't put multiple arguments as a single string in the configuration, as that will be passed to the command as a single argument. I also recommend you take a look through [the GCC online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for your version of GCC, and learn what the `-g` flag really does (it should also be easy to find out that information by a quick search).

Comment: And then a general tip about multi-file projects: Don't build it using `gcc` or `g++` directly. Instead I suggest you learn about tools like *make* or *CMake*  or *Meson*  or similar, where you can easily create multi-file "projects" and build them. Such tools can also keep track of dependencies and build-dates, so if you change a header file then all sources depending on the header file will be rebuilt, and only rebuild files that have actually been modified (so you don't rebuild all sources all the time).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I really did a lot of searches but I couldn't find exactly what I needed. Thank you I'll learn more about that!

Comment: @TedLyngmo It was a suggested tag, I already corrected it thanks to you!